# How to remove duplicated values in distributed system?

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, distributed-system

Assume we have a distributed system and there are K machines in the cluster. Each machine stores several integers. I would like to remove all the duplicate values from the system. So if integer 123 appears in machine1 and machine2, we should only keep one 123 in the system. How should I handle this?

My idea is to first let each machine do a removeDuplicate operation using something like bucket-sorting (all nubmers are integer), and then let one machine be the master-node to do a reduce. Is there any better idea?

Comment: Your question is very interesting but unfortunately quite broad and off-topic for SO. Nevertheless, it's mainly about good partitioning which should shuffle the data all over the network and sorting than map partition with a low upper bound complexity then reduce by the end

Comment: What are the integers used for and what are the intended outputs?

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer would be to not end up with unmanaged duplicate values on different machines in the first place, by using a distributed hash ring or similar technology to make sure a certain value ends up on a certain node.

If that's not good enough, I'd look into heuristic optimizations. Since you already have multiple copies on different machines, I'm assuming that you want to deduplicate these values for a little bit of extra performance, rather than application correctness.

If this is the case, let each node slowly pass through its keyspace (foreach integer on node) and ask all other nodes if they have a copy of that same value. If they do, we deduplicate it. If someone doesn't respond (fast enough); ignore them and continue. This allows for a decentralized deduplication algorithm that handles node failures and that can be run in any speed, allowing more important traffic to be prioritized when needed.

I'm guessing that the keys are accessed according to a power law distribution, so sweaping through the most commonly updated keys more often could be more efficient, but there's no guarantee for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what type of system you are interested in but if a shared memory is an option you can keep a counter array. Since all your numbers are integers you can flag each integer that appears in this shared array. Also, if this integer is already flagged then drop it. This will result in o(k) operations for each integer received and no duplicates.